# C# Validating input for textbox on winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, validation

I want to check what the user is writing in a textbox before I save it in a database. What is the best way to do this? I guess I can always write some ifs or some try-catch blocks, but I was wondering if there's a better method. I've read something about Validating Events, but I am not sure how can I use them.

Comment: Can I make a recommendation that you start migrating from WinForms to a more modern platform

Answer (score 54, accepted):

#### Description

There are many ways to validate your TextBox. You can do this on every keystroke, at a later time, or on the `Validating` event.

The `Validating` event gets fired if your TextBox looses focus. When the user clicks on a other Control, for example. If your set `e.Cancel = true` the TextBox doesn't lose the focus.

> **MSDN - Control.Validating Event** When you change the focus by using the keyboard (TAB, SHIFT+TAB, and so on), by calling the Select or SelectNextControl methods, or by setting the ContainerControl.ActiveControl property to the current form, focus events occur in the following order
>
> Enter
>
> GotFocus
>
> Leave
>
> Validating
>
> Validated
>
> LostFocus
>
> When you change the focus by using the mouse or by calling the Focus method, focus events occur in the following order:
>
> Enter
>
> GotFocus
>
> LostFocus
>
> Leave
>
> Validating
>
> Validated

#### Sample Validating Event

```
private void textBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text != "something")
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```

### Update

You can use the `ErrorProvider` to visualize that your TextBox is not valid.
Check out [Using Error Provider Control in Windows Forms and C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/DipalChoksi/UsingErrorProviderContolinWindowsFormsandCSharp11242005010829AM/UsingErrorProviderContolinWindowsFormsandCSharp.aspx)

#### More Information

- [MSDN - Control.Validating Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating.aspx)
- [MSDN - ErrorProvider Component (Windows Forms)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95ysxkwy.aspx)
- [Using Error Provider Control in Windows Forms and C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/DipalChoksi/UsingErrorProviderContolinWindowsFormsandCSharp11242005010829AM/UsingErrorProviderContolinWindowsFormsandCSharp.aspx)

Answer (score 9):

With WinForms you can use the ErrorProvider in conjunction with the `Validating` event to handle the validation of user input. The `Validating` event provides the hook to perform the validation and ErrorProvider gives a nice consistent approach to providing the user with feedback on any error conditions.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.aspx

Comment: Beware though: The ErrorProvider component does not provide built-in support for accessibility clients. To make your application accessible when using this component, you must provide an additional, accessible feedback mechanism. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.aspx#Anchor_7)