# Validation in Windows form using c# in .net

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, textbox

I am doing my project in VS2012 Windows Forms using C#.

My probem is I am validating a textbox when the control loses focus; check it is empty or not. My textbox name is `ChildFirstName` and my code is:

```
private void ChildFirstName_Leave(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    if (ChildFirstName.Text == String.Empty)
    {
        ChildFirstName.Focus();
        ChildFirstName.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

But this is not working can anybody say what is the actual problem?

Comment: What is you goal exactly? I suppose you want the `BackColor` of the textbox to turn red, right? Not `ForeColor`

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Validating input for textbox on winforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915151/c-sharp-validating-input-for-textbox-on-winforms)

Comment: Code is entering IF statement?

Answer (score 1):

There is a flaw in the code you have written. `ForeColor` property is used to define text color and not background color. So in your code you make a check if the there is no text then the change the color of the text to red. It does not make much sense to me.

If you wish to change the background color of the textbox then use `BackColor` property.

```
    private void ValidateTextBox(object sender)
    {
        TextBox textBox = (sender as TextBox);
        if (textBox == null)
            return;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text))
        {
            textBox.Focus();
            textBox.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
```

Call above method in your leave event of textboxes.

Hope it helps.