# User input validation using TextBox_Validating event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, validation, validating

I'm trying to use this custom method for user input validation in text boxes. But I see something missing here as now I cannot move (focus) to next text box in the form!

```
private void textBox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox currenttb = (TextBox)sender;
    if (currenttb.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Empty field {0 }", currenttb.Name.Substring(3)));
        e.Cancel = false;
    }

    else
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Adding the handler to the textboxes with a foreach loop in the form constructor:

```
foreach(TextBox tb in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(x => x.CausesValidation == true))
{
    tb.Validating += textBox_Validating;
}
```

Comment: It is the expected behaviour - [Control.Validating Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: There is a mistake in `if`. Should be like this > if (currenttb.Text == "")
{
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Empty field {0 }", currenttb.Name.Substring(3)));
e.Cancel = true ;
}

Comment: if you set e.Cancel = true, means validation failed, then it will not allow to change the focus

Answer (score 1):

As answerd here its expected behaviour of loosing the focus [C# Validating input for textbox on winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915151/c-sharp-validating-input-for-textbox-on-winforms) :-

> Description
>
> There are many ways to validate your TextBox. You can do this on every
>   keystroke, at a later time or the Validating Event.
>
> The Validating Event gets fired if your TextBox looses the focus, for
>   example click on a other Control. If your set e.Cancel = true the
>   TextBox don't loose the focus.
>
> MSDN - Control.Validating Event When you change the focus by using the
>   keyboard (TAB, SHIFT+TAB, and so on), by calling the Select or
>   SelectNextControl methods, or by setting the
>   ContainerControl.ActiveControl property to the current form, focus
>   events occur in the following order
>
> Enter
>
> GotFocus
>
> Leave
>
> Validating
>
> Validated
>
> LostFocus
>
> When you change the focus by using the mouse or by calling the Focus
>   method, focus events occur in the following order:
>
> Enter
>
> GotFocus
>
> LostFocus
>
> Leave
>
> Validating
>
> Validated