# Validating TextBox only accept alphabetic/lowercase characters

Tags: c#, validation

I have code for validating text_box which only accept alphabetic/lowercase characters. I have managed to add the code in the below code.

This is my code:

```
if (char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == 8)
{
    e.handled = false;
}
else
{
    e.handled = true;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915151/c-sharp-validating-input-for-textbox-on-winforms

Comment: Ok, you really need to go back and think through your post. I had a really hard time trying to clean this up, and it's still at a point where I don't understand what you want.

Comment: Also, I removed your leading `{` and fixed the type on `IsLetter`. Always post code that compiles!

Comment: You aren't asking a question.

Comment: @gunr2171 for your stress. `e.keychar` doesn't exist. `e.KeyChar` is the correct one :-).

Comment: @Steve, correct. I didn't know what the method this lives in was, so I didn't bother fixing that.

Comment: sorry for that i just typed it so i know that too its case sensetive but i just wanted code for alphabet and i had asked that can i managed the code on that program or not if no than fine i will remove it but which code should i use then...and i told u that i am begineer in c# mistake happens by human being

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below

```
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    TextBox1.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Lower;
}

private void TextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = !char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar);
}
```

Basically what I am doing here is

1. In the constructor I am setting the textbox to convert any character typed to lower case
2. Add a KeyPress event to the textbox and check the character typed is not a letter or character 8.