# On leaving a control, how can I give that control focus again?

Tags: c#, forms, focus, controls

I've got TextBoxes in a C# form.  The user enters data, and then when they leave the control (almost always by hitting Tab), I check the data to make sure it's valid.  If it is invalid, I want to highlight their text so they can immediately fix it rather than having to click it.

Right now, on Control.Leave, I validate their entry. This works just fine.  However, since they hit Tab, right after they dismiss the error message, it goes on to the next object, even though I've got (`(TextBox)sender).Focus();`

How can I have the above line fire *after* the form Tabs to the next control.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into Control.CausesValidation property

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.causesvalidation(v=vs.110).aspx

You can validate the control prior to the user leaving focus rather than waiting on Focus moving itself.

And here's MSDN documentation for Control.Validating event, does a good job at laying out the sequence of events when gaining / losing focus of a Control.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating(v=vs.110).aspx

Notice how Control.Validating and Control.Validated are launched prior to Control.LostFocus. You can perform your validation step *prior* to allowing the user to lose focus of your Textbox.

There's also a pretty good previous answer on stackoverflow.com which outlines how to do this: [C# Validating input for textbox on winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915151/c-sharp-validating-input-for-textbox-on-winforms)

Answer (score 1):

If you handle the [Control.Validating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event, setting e.Cancel to true will stop the change of focus from occurring.

Note that this method will also stop buttons from working, so you may need to set [Control.CausesValidation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.causesvalidation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to false on certain buttons.

You will also need the following snippet on the main form to allow the close button to work:

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e) {
    e.Cancel = false;
    base.OnFormClosing(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `LostFocus` event on the `TextBox` to Focus it again